# How can Image Caption work?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, object-detection, feature-extraction

I have two models and a file contains captions for images. The output of model 1 is *.pkl* files that contain the features of the images. Model 2 is the language model that will be trained with the captions. How can I link between two models to predict a caption for any image? The output of model 1 should be the input of model 2. But the features only are not enough so the input of model 2 will be *.pkl* files + caption file. Right?

If someone can help me in getting the link between the two models, I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Standard Image Captioning Pipeline is to train the model in a single batch(or *mini-batch*) i.e. get the features from the CNN Image encoder and then feed that into an RNN decoder (features + Real Captions) to produce output captions for the Image.

The training loop in PyTorch would look something like this:

```
# zero the parameter gradients
decoder.zero_grad()
encoder.zero_grad()
        
# Forward pass
features = encoder(image)
outputs = decoder(features, captions)
        
# Compute the Loss
loss = criterion(outputs.view(-1, vocab_size), 
                         captions.view(-1))
        
# Backward pass.
loss.backward()
        
# Update the parameters in the optimizer.
optimizer.step()
```

I'd suggest you go through the paper [Show and Tell: A Neural Image Caption Generator](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4555v2.pdf).

I also made this [Kaggle Kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/sauravmaheshkar/neural-image-captioning) implementing the paper from scratch. Should help clear up any other doubts.

Comment: thanks for replying , should I train the language model for the captions of my own dataset separately? 
Will I need the class code separately to link between the two models?

Comment: Yes you should train the RNN decoder for your particular dataset separately again (for best performance). I'm not able to understand your second question, can you please clarify

Comment: i have the two models separately .. i didn't write the  code that makes a caption for the image yet. how can i start for the linking between them